# Recommendation on ADM mass and Bondi mass

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, resource-recommendations, momentum, hamiltonian-formalism

I want to learn some advanced topics in GR, such as [ADM 4-momentum and Bondi 4-momentum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_general_relativity). However nearly no textbooks on GR contain this area, such as Wald, MTW, Hawking, Carroll and  Zee's. Can anyone recommend some textbooks or papers giving the elaboration in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is discussed in detail in A Relativists Toolkit by Eric Poisson.  The original ADM paper is on the arxiv at http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0405109, and while the notation is old, the arguments are clear.

Answer (score 2):

There's a discussion of this stuff in Wald, pp. 291ff. It must be a pretty accessible treatment, because I was able to understand some of it. The style is Wald's usual dry, mathematical, concise one, but he also gives some simple interpretations.